# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{x} \tan(y)= \frac{1}{x^2} \tan(y)\sin(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve the differential equation
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{x} \tan(y)= \frac{1}{x^2} \tan(y)\sin(y)$$

Hints please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pose $y = \arcsin(xz)$. Then:

$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2z^2}}\frac{dz}{dx}\\
\tan(y) = \tan(\arcsin(xz)) = \displaystyle\frac{xz}{\sqrt{1-x^2z^2}}\\
\sin(y) = \sin(\arcsin(xz)) = xz
\end{cases}$$

Then:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{x} \tan(y)= \frac{1}{x^2} \tan(y)\sin(y) \Rightarrow\\
\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2z^2}}\frac{dz}{dx} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{xz}{\sqrt{1-x^2z^2}}= \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{xz}{\sqrt{1-x^2z^2}}xz \Rightarrow\\
\frac{dz}{dx} + \frac{1}{x}z = \frac{1}{x}z^2.$$

This is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) with $Q(x) = P(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. The solution is $$z(x) = \frac{1}{ax + 1}.$$

Finally:

$$y(x) = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{ax + 1}\right)$$

Comment: How did you know we have to substitute arcsin(xz) ?

Comment: just an intuition

Comment: Very strange intuition!Is this a common problem or something?

Comment: Not so strange if you consider that there are $\tan$ and $\sin$ function. Honestly, never saw this before. Another way is to use just $y = \arcsin(z)$ or $\arctan(z)$. I think these can also work.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta If you are in need of some, [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27[t]+%2B+Tan[y[t]]%2Ft+%3D%3D+1%2Ft^2+Tan[y[t]]+Sin[y[t]]) is a common source of intuition these days:)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$y'(x)+\frac{1}{x}\tan(y(x))=\frac{1}{x^2}\tan(y(x))\sin(y(x))\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)+\frac{\tan(y(x))}{x}=\frac{\tan(y(x))\sin(y(x))}{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $y(x)=\sin^{-1}(v(x))$, which gives $\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\frac{\text{d}v(x)}{\text{d}x}}{\sqrt{1-v(x)^2}}$:

---

$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}v(x)}{\text{d}x}}{\sqrt{-v(x)^2+1}}+\frac{v(x)}{x\sqrt{-v(x)^2+1}}=\frac{v(x)^2}{x^2\sqrt{-v(x)^2+1}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{x\frac{\text{d}v(x)}{\text{d}x}+v(x)}{x\sqrt{-v(x)^2+1}}=\frac{v(x)^2}{x^2\sqrt{-v(x)^2+1}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{\frac{\text{d}v(x)}{\text{d}x}}{v(x)^2}-\frac{1}{xv(x)}=-\frac{1}{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $u=(x)=\frac{1}{v(x)}$, which gives $\frac{\text{d}u(x)}{\text{d}x}=-\frac{\frac{\text{d}v(x)}{\text{d}x}}{v(x)^2}$:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}u(x)}{\text{d}x}-\frac{u(x)}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$